# Attempt to add "Spring Data JPA" to "project generated by Heroku"

Tags: spring, heroku, dependencies, spring-data-jpa, pom.xml

I would like to add **Spring Data JPA** to **Java-project generated by Heroku**. Berofe I tried to do this, a template of the application was working properly on Heroku-domain and local. Here you will find properly functioning the source code: https://github.com/plkpiotr/fifa-backend/tree/912b8c468aeb86834423fb8a70e5c532cdc1fe1b

Dependencies before changes were as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>java-getting-started</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/>
</parent>
<name>java-getting-started</name>

<properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <webjars-bootstrap.version>4.1.0</webjars-bootstrap.version>
  <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.12.1</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
  <webjars-jquery.version>3.3.1-1</webjars-jquery.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
      <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>build-info</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <additionalProperties>
              <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
              <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
              <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
              <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
            </additionalProperties>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Later, I tried to add these dependencies to launch JPA:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But, the error is still the same:

```
  _    _                _
 | |  | |              | |
 | |__| | ___ _ __ ___ | | ___   _
 |  __  |/ _ \ '__/ _ \| |/ / | | |
 | |  | |  __/ | | (_) |   <| |_| |
 |_|  |_|\___|_|  \___/|_|\_\\__,_|

:: Built with Spring Boot :: 2.0.1.RELEASE

2018-07-10 10:50:05.203  INFO 13468 --- [  restartedMain] io.github.plkpiotr.Main                  : Starting Main on aps00076856-mb with PID 13468 (C:\fifa-backend\target\classes started by Piotr.Palka in C:\fifa-backend)
2018-07-10 10:50:05.203  INFO 13468 --- [  restartedMain] io.github.plkpiotr.Main                  : The following profiles are active: production
2018-07-10 10:50:05.313  INFO 13468 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@30866333: startup date [Tue Jul 10 10:50:05 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/Piotr.Palka/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-07-10 10:50:07.292  INFO 13468 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fedb7acf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-10 10:50:07.612  INFO 13468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
2018-07-10 10:50:07.628  INFO 13468 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-07-10 10:50:07.628  INFO 13468 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
2018-07-10 10:50:07.628  INFO 13468 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;%M2_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Users\Piotr.Palka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Piotr.Palka\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.5.4\\bin;;.]
2018-07-10 10:50:07.748  INFO 13468 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-10 10:50:07.748  INFO 13468 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2435 ms
2018-07-10 10:50:08.060 ERROR 13468 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6dbfcc55]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2018-07-10 10:50:08.076  INFO 13468 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-07-10 10:50:08.092  WARN 13468 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-07-10 10:50:08.092  INFO 13468 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-10 10:50:08.107 ERROR 13468 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    (...)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    (...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6dbfcc55]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    (...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6dbfcc55]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    (...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6dbfcc55]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    (...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6dbfcc55]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    (...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6dbfcc55]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    (...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6dbfcc55]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    (...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'main': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    (...)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    (...)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've lost a whole day's work stuck in here. It is finally working now.
The solution is as follows:

I created new project by following: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/spring-boot-memcache (instead of https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction as before) But the tutorials are incomplete and inaccurate, so I decided to leave little clues:

1. Use https://start.spring.io/ to choose needed dependencies.
2. `git commit -m "message"` instead of `git commit -m 'message'`
3. Enter:
   `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and `server.port=${PORT:8080}` in application.properties
4. If the application still doesn't work try in the terminal: `heroku ps:scale web=1` in Heroku CLI in the correct catalogue.
5. Procfile can't have apostrophes, only: `web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/*.jar`